# How to retrieve data for a JavaFX table from a JPA entity in relation with another one?

Tags: java, jpa, javafx

I'm retrieving some data from multiple tables in JPA.
Here's the first entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "source")
public class Source implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "sourceid", nullable = false)
    private String sourceId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "flux")
    private Flux flux;

    // Other attributes
    // Constructors, getters and setters
}
```

And here's the second entity, that is referenced from the first one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "flux")
public class Flux implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private FluxId fluxId = new FluxId();
    @Column(name = "value")
    private BigDecimal value;
    @Column(name = "error")
    private BigDecimal error;

    // Other attributes
    // Constructors, getters and setters
}
```

I want to display the data of these tables in a single JavaFX table. How to do that? Here's what I was trying to do, but the columns of `flux.value` and `flux.error` are always empty. How to fix this?

```
// Source table setup
    sourceIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("sourceId"));
    fluxColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flux.value")); // Value of the flux
    errorColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flux.error")); // Error of the flux
    // More columns definition from sources attributes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement the cell value factories directly, instead of using `PropertyValueFactory` (which does not support "properties of properties").

I assume the table is a `TableView<Source>` and `fluxColumn` and `errorColumn` are both `TableColumn<Source, BigDecimal>`. Then you can do

```
fluxColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().getFlux‌​().getValue()));
errorColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().getFlux‌​().getError()));
```

If you implement your entities with the [JavaFX properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) (and use [JPA Property Access](http://svanimpe.be/blog/properties-jpa.html)) then you can retrieve the existing properties, instead of creating new ones each time:

```
fluxColumn.setCellValueProperty(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getFlux().valueProperty());
errorColumn.setCellValueProperty(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getFlux().errorProperty());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that to make a model class, for example FluxModel:

```
public class FluxModel {

private LongProperty id;
private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> value;
private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> error;

    public FluxModel(
            Long id,
            BigDecimal value,
            BigDecimal error) {
        this.id = new SimpleLongProperty(id);
        this.value = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(value);
        this.error = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(error);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public LongProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        return value.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> valueProperty() {
        return value;
    }

    public BigDecimal getError() {
        return error.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> errorProperty() {
        return error;
    }
}
```

in your controller class:

```
@FXML
private TableView<FluxModel> table;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FluxModel, Long> sourceIdColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FluxModel, BigDecimal> fluxColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<FluxModel, BigDecimal> errorColumn;
```

then as cellValueFactories:

```
sourceIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(data-> data.getValue().idProperty().asObject());
fluxColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().valueProperty());
errorColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().errorProperty());
```

You may have to add `StringConverter`s to the cells.

Then you need a list to store the data:

```
private ObservableList<FluxModel> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

you can populate it, and you have to

```
table.setItems(tableData);
```